# Making Select Boxes Have Database Entry Set As Selected in PHP

Tags: php, html, html-select

How would I go about setting the "selected" attribute to one of these boxes, based on what value is stored in the $genre variable?

i.e. If $genre == "Puzzle" then

```
<option value=Puzzle>
```

becomes

```
<option value=Puzzle selected>
```

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM release_dates WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$genre = $row['game_genre'];
?>


<select name=genre>
<option value=Action>Action</option>
<option value=Adventure>Adventure</option>
<option value=Puzzle>Puzzle</option>
<option value=RPG>RPG</option>
<option value=Horror>Horror</option>
<option value=Shooter>Shooter</option>
<option value=Simulator>Simulator</option>
<option value=Sport>Sport</option>
<option value=Strategy>Strategy</option>
</select>
```

Also, for extra brownie points, how would this apply to select boxes with the "multiple" attribute?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's pretty simple actually:

```
<option value=Action <?php $genre == "Action" ? "selected":""?> >Action</option>
```

Just use a ternary operator `(condition) ? true:false` to input "selected" if the value is set. Simply duplicate that logic on all the options:

```
<option value=Action <?php $genre == "Action" ? "selected":""?> >Action</option>
<option value=Adventure <?php $genre == "Adventure" ? "selected":""?> >Adventure</option>
<option value=Puzzle <?php $genre == "Puzzle" ? "selected":""?> >Puzzle</option>
<option value=RPG <?php $genre == "RPG" ? "selected":""?> >RPG</option>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because it works for both normal and multiple select boxes. Also, I learned about the ternary operator. Many Thanks! :)

Comment: I know, they're amazing! Plus you can put ternary operations inside other ternary operations for sudo `if/elseif/if` one line statements!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foreach` loop to iterate over your options, and each time, perform a check using an if statement to see if it matches:

```
foreach ($genres as $genre) {
    if ($genre === "Puzzle") {
        echo '<option value="'.$genre.'" selected>'.$genre.'</option>';
    else {
        echo '<option value="'.$genre.'">'.$genre.'</option>';
    }
}
```

By the way, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions anymore as they are unsafe, [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and will be removed from PHP in the future. Take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: up vote for mentioning PDO, because it's the right way to go with the database, unless you are using a framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="Strategy" <?php if($genre == "Strategy"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >Strategy</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a version that keeps everything in PHP

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM release_dates WHERE id = ". $id;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// possible options
$genre_options = array(
    'Action'
    'Adventure'
    'Puzzle'
    'RPG'
    'Horror'
    'Shooter'
    'Simulator'
    'Sport'
    'Strategy'
);

// loop over the options, and wrap them in tags
$options = '';
foreach ($genre_options as $genre) {

        // check if we have a match
        $selected = '';
        if ($genre == $row['game_genre']) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        }

        $options .= '<option value="'. $genre .'" '. $selected .'>'. $genre .'</option>'
}

echo '
<select name=genre>
    '. $options .'
</select>
';
?>
```

What this does is create an array of possible genre's, loop over them, and see if any of them match the genre that was returned from the query. If thats the case it will add the `selected="selected"` attribute.

Unfortunately I'll be missing out on the "brownie points", because I'm not able to help you with the multi-select.

Let me know if this helps!

EDIT: I also noted that in your query you where passing the `$id` variable as a string. Fixed that in the query in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining your genres using plain HTML, create an array with all your genres.

To do so:

```
$genres = array(
    "Action",
    "Adventure",
    "Puzzle",
    "RPG",
    "Horror",
    "Shooter",
    "Simulator",
    "Sport",
    "Strategy"
);

foreach($genres as $currentGenre) {
    echo "<option value="'.$currentGenre.'" '.($currentGenre == $genre ? "selected" : "").'>'.$currentGenre.'</option>';
}
```

What this does, is loop over all your genres and create a single `<option>` for each of them. If the `$currentGenre` (so one of the genres from the array `$genres`) matches `$genre` (which you pulled from MySQL), it selects that option using a inline if-statement.